# Converter Data dd/mm/aaaa para Formato ISO 8601 (aaaa-mm-dd)

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

Tenho um campo chamado `maskedTextBox2` no C# Windows Form, que contém uma máscara para data no formato `dd/mm/aaaa`. Como posso fazer para converter essa *string* em formato `aaaa-mm-dd` para salvar no banco MySQL, que usa datas no formato ISO 8601 (`aaaa-mm-dd`)?

Comment: Você tentou utilizar a função STR_TO_DATE? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: não tinha tentado ainda, mas funcionou, vlw!

Comment: Editei para acertar o formato da data. O formato aaaa-mm-dd do MySQL não é inglês, mas sim padronizado de acordo com a ISO 8601.

Comment: http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aqui tem um exemplo que deve te ajudar, vou copiar ele abaixo para facilitar: [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc165448.aspx).

**Como converter uma cadeia de caracteres em um *DateTime* (Guia de Programação em C#)**

É comum que os programas permitem que os usuários insiram datas como valores de cadeia de caracteres. Para converter uma data cadeia de caracteres com base em um objeto de [`System.DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.datetime.aspx), você pode usar o método de [`Convert.ToDateTime(String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/xhz1w05e.aspx) ou o método estático de [`DateTime.Parse(String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/1k1skd40.aspx), conforme mostrado no exemplo o seguir.

```
// Date strings are interpreted according to the current culture.
// If the culture is en-US, this is interpreted as "January 8, 2008",
// but if the user's computer is fr-FR, this is interpreted as "August 1, 2008"
string date = "01/08/2008";
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);            
Console.WriteLine("Year: {0}, Month: {1}, Day: {2}", dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day);

// Specify exactly how to interpret the string.
IFormatProvider culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR", true);

// Alternate choice: If the string has been input by an end user, you might 
// want to format it according to the current culture:
// IFormatProvider culture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse(date, culture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
Console.WriteLine("Year: {0}, Month: {1}, Day {2}", dt2.Year, dt2.Month, dt2.Day);

/* Output (assuming first culture is en-US and second is fr-FR):
Year: 2008, Month: 1, Day: 8
Year: 2008, Month: 8, Day 1
*/
```

Comment: Também funcionou, vlw!

Comment: @Augusto Blz, qualquer dúvida manda aew!

Answer (score 4):

Se tens de interpretar um formato específico independente da cultura, usa o [método DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/System.DateTime.ParseExact.aspx):

```
DateTime.ParseExact("01/04/2014", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Nunca usei MySQL, mas para o SQL Server eu nunca usaria texto (a não ser que a data seja guardada como texto na base de dados). Usaria um `SqlCommand` com `SqlParameter`s.