# Converter uma data no formato yyyy-dd-mm para dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estou tentando fazer uma pesquisa na minha base de dados em que o objectivo é pesquisar entre duas datas inseridas pelo utilizador, e que ele me apresenta os valores todos que se encontram nesse intervalo de datas, mas não estou conseguindo ir buscar a data na `texbox` porque dá erro de formato. Quero apresentar o resultado da pesquisa numa GridView

```
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT idConduta,valor_Lido FROM valores_conduta WHERE data_Leitura BETWEEN " + txtDataInicio.Text + " AND " + txtDataInicio.Text + "", conn);

 da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

 DataSet ds = new DataSet();//definir o objecto dadaset (ds)

 //preencher os dados
 da.Fill(ds);
 GridView1.DataSource = ds;
 GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Qual é o erro de formato?

Comment: É isto que você quer? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11065/converter-data-dd-mm-aaaa-para-formato-iso-8601-aaaa-mm-dd

Answer (score 1):

Podes utilizar o `.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")` na tua data (tem de ser uma data válida), ficando:

```
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT idConduta,valor_Lido FROM valores_conduta WHERE data_Leitura BETWEEN " + txtDataInicio.Text.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + " AND " + txtDataInicio.Text.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")** + "", conn);
```

Ou então podes converter a data antes da tua consulta:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDataInicio.Text, "yyyy-dd-mm", 
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

E utilizas a variável `dt` na tua consulta.

Comment: Tem um bug porque a data começa em dd-mm-yyyy 00:00:00 ate dd-mm-yyyy 23:59:59

Comment: Então no `.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")` basta fazer `.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")`

Comment: O txtDataInicio.Text é String, nao DateTime. Erro: The best overloaded method match for 'string.ToString(System.IFormatProvider)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Se é string fazes o exemplo de baixo. Convertes para DateTime para depois converteres para o formato String que queres

Comment: Ok obrigada vou tentar fazer isso ja te dou um feedback!!

Comment: Fiz assim e da me um erro de sintaxe outra vez, mas com o debugg deu para ver que ele esta a ir buscar o formato que eu quero, mas quando faz preencher o dataset com o dataadapter ele queixa se DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDataInicio.Text, "yyyy-M-d",
                                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                dt1.ToString("d-M-yyyy");

Comment: Pois, isso já é uma questão diferente, e na qual não estou a ver uma solução...